# Cannot Group By on multiple columns and Count

Tags: c#, linq, count, group-by, linq-to-entities

I want to write this simple query with Linq:

```
select issuercode,securitycode,dataprocessingflag,COUNT(issuercode) as cnt 
from cmr_invhdr
where ProcessedLike <> 'STMNT ONLY'
group by issuercode,securitycode,dataprocessingflag
order by Issuercode
```

I've tried the following code but I get this error( DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
Parameter name: input) :

```
 var lstCMRInvHdrNips = (from r in e.CMR_INVHDR
                         where r.ProcessedLike != "STMNT ONLY"
                         select new { 
                                        r.IssuerCode, 
                                        r.SecurityCode, 
                                        CountofIssuerCode = r.IssuerCode.Count(),
                                        r.DataProcessingFlag 
                                    }
                         ).GroupBy(x => 
                                       new { 
                                               x.IssuerCode, 
                                               x.SecurityCode, 
                                               x.DataProcessingFlag, 
                                               x.CountofIssuerCode 
                                           }
                                   ).OrderBy(x => x.Key.IssuerCode).ToList();
```

Comment: You can try with re-ordering your `select` statement (put `count` column at the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any sense to count `issuercode` while grouping by this field at once? As when groupped by a field, it's `COUNT` will always be 1.

Probably you should not group by `issuercode` and count it after the `GroupBy` in a separate `Select` statement:

```
var result = e.CMR_INVHDR
              .Where(r => r.ProcessedLike != "STMNT ONLY")
              .GroupBy(r => new { r.SecurityCode, r.DataProcessingFlag })
              .Select(r => new 
              { 
                  Value = r.Key, 
                  IssuerCodesCount = r.GroupBy(g => g.IssuerCode).Count() 
              })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, I've change my query to this(using yours) and it worked, but still I can't underestand what was wrong with mine                    var result = e.CMR_INVHDR
               .Where(r => r.ProcessedLike != "STMNT ONLY")
               .GroupBy(r => new { r.IssuerCode, r.SecurityCode, r.DataProcessingFlag })
               .OrderBy(r => r.Key.IssuerCode)
               .Select(r => new { IssuerCode = r.Key.IssuerCode, SecurityCode = r.Key.SecurityCode, DataProcessingFlag=r.Key.DataProcessingFlag, Count = r.Count() })
               .ToList();

Comment: @MinaN your query is run without errors, but it groups by `IssuerCode`; it means that each group contains entries with one and the same `IssuerCode` only. That's why `COUNT(IssuerCode)` results into 1 in every group.

Comment: @MinaN at first you should make it clear: whether you need to group by `IssuerCode` (and order by it then) or on the contrary you need to count distinct `IssuerCode` in groups

Comment: @MinaN if you do need to group by `IssuerCode`, then it should not be the field to count by. Then you need to count all entries: i.e. simply `.Count()` in LINQ (as `COUNT(*)` in transact-sql); or count by some other field (a private key, probably?). A least - not `IssuerCode`